# What is the difference between R. java and resources?

Tags: java, android

I thought Resources consisted of mostly front-end stuff of the android app while you had java code doing the logic work, android app. development on a high level was divided in these two parts. However, there is a R.java file that contains identifiers for all resources in android app, but the R is also short name for Resources? So does this mean there are two things by the same name in android dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android R.java is an auto-generated file by aapt (Android Asset Packaging Tool) that contains resource IDs for all the resources of res/ directory.

so if you add an image to your drawable file it will generate an ID in R.java file

Comment: Does this mean that the R.java just contains the ids for all the resources within the android application? Both are separate things then from my understanding.